# Explain: ruby -run -e httpd

Tags: ruby

I know that this command will serve file and folders from the current directory but how does it work? I know that `-e` allows to run the statement from the command line. But I could not find any info about `-run` switch. Also, I could now find method httpd which according to [this](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/httpd) should be on the `Object`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But I could not find any info about `-run` switch.

There is no `-run` switch. There is an `-r` switch (which is simply equivalent to `require`ing the named file) and an [`un` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/un/rdoc/). Just like there was no `-rubygems` switch in Ruby 1.9—2.4, there was the `-r` switch and an `ubygems` library (which was removed in Ruby 2.5).

> Also, I could now find method httpd which according to [this](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/httpd) should be on the `Object`

There seems to be a bug with either the RDoc documentation generation or Ruby-Doc.org; [the documentation of the `un` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/un/rdoc/) is empty, but [the method is there](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/un.rb#L304-L352). Note that [YARD](http://yardoc.org/) seems to process the documentation correctly, as can be seen on the [RubyDoc.info version of the same documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/un/toplevel:httpd).

Comment: It would've been useful to mention this in the man page for ruby. At least don't break the assumption that if I do `ruby --help | grep '\-run'` I should find _something_. But yea, thanks for the info!

Comment: On my system, `-r` is documented both in `ruby --help` (`-rlibrary          require the library before executing your script`) and in the manpage (`-r library          Causes Ruby to load the library using require.  It is useful when using -n or -p.`).

Comment: I understand, but given that `-r` is a short option, I was expecting `-run` to be a contraction of `-r -u -n`, which is not the case. They should have at least mentioned `un.rb` in the manpage, so that people are not left scratching their heads as to how `-run` as an option works.

Comment: You can't add every possible library that has ever been written and will ever be written to the documentation. Or do you want extra documentation for `-rubygems`, `-rfoo`, `-rbar`, `-rickroll`, `-rocknroll`, `-rdate`, `-rnokogiri`, `-ractive_support`, etc. as well?